# Error while executing tcl file in ns2

Tags: ns2

My Blackhole-AODV program was running smoothly before, there were no errors and i recorded quite a no. of results from the simulations. But after installing xgraph( i thought plotting results in xgraph would be nice and not by doing it manually) my program stopped working. It's showing some long error and i don't know how to fix it. Please help i tried to find many solutions on net(there were same kind of problems everywhere but NO SOLUTION!!!).The error is given below:-

```
num_nodes is set 50
warning: Please use -channel as shown in tcl/ex/wireless-mitf.tcl
INITIALIZE THE LIST xListHead

(_o872 cmd line 1)
invoked from within
"_o872 cmd addr"
invoked from within
"catch "$self cmd $args" ret"
invoked from within
"if [catch "$self cmd $args" ret] {
set cls [$self info class]
global errorInfo
set savedInfo $errorInfo
error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."
(procedure "_o872" line 2)
(SplitObject unknown line 2)
invoked from within
"_o872 addr"
("eval" body line 1)
invoked from within
"eval $node addr $args"
("default" arm line 2)
invoked from within
"switch -exact $routingAgent_ {
 DSDV {
 set ragent [$self create-dsdv-agent $node]
 }
DSR {
$self at 0.0 "$node start-dsr"
}
AODV {
set ragent [$self cre..."
(procedure "_o3" line 14)
(Simulator create-wireless-node line 14)
invoked from within
"_o3 create-wireless-node"
("eval" body line 1)
invoked from within
"eval $self create-wireless-node $args"
(procedure "_o3" line 23)
(Simulator node line 23)
invoked from within
"$ns_ node"
("for" body line 2)
invoked from within
"for {set i $val(nnaodv) } {$i<$val(nn) } {incr i} {  
  set node_($i) [$ns_ node]
  $node_($i) random-motion 1;
  $node_($i) color red
  $ns_ at 0.0 "$nod..."
  (file "atk20.tcl" line 69)
```

Answer (score 0):

---

There is a blackholeaodv / Xgraph example in "xgraph_ns2-files-tcl_21Apr2015.tar.gz" →

→ https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNa2t3OUJaV2lydUk/view?usp=sharing

I.e. it's easier to add 'Blackhole' to an existing AODV file, than it is to make an existing "Blackholeaodv simulation" generate output files for Xgraph.

---

Blackholeaodv INFO ...

. http://network-simulator-ns-2.7690.n7.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=search_page&node=2&query=blackhole&days=0&sort=date

. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/ns-users/blackhole|sort:date

. http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/tags/blackhole/

---

[ns2](/questions/tagged/ns2)[xgraph](/questions/tagged/xgraph)[blackhole](/questions/tagged/blackhole)